# Write appointment without user confirmation using WinRT Appointments API

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, appointment

I'm experimenting with the new WinRT Appointments API in Windows 8.1, based on a sample provided on the MSDN website of Microsoft: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Appointments-API-sample-2b55c76e

It works great and I can add appointments without a hassle, but there's always a confirmation by the user involved when using the method `ShowAddAppointmentAsync` from the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentManager` namespace, which shows the Appointments provider Add Appointment UI.

I'm looking for a solution to add a larger collection of appointments in the default Windows 8 calendar, WITHOUT the confirmation for each individual appointment in the collection. Is there a way to get around this and bulk insert appointments? Maybe the Windows Live SDK?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826523.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Its true that the API prompts the user before saving, but there is a provision to achieve this.

```
var appointment = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.Appointment();
    appointment.details = "This is a dummy appointment";
    appointment.reminder = 15000;
    appointment.subject = "TEST APPPOINTMENT";

    var x = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentManager.requestStoreAsync(Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentStoreAccessType.appCalendarsReadWrite).done(function (apppointmentStore) {
        apppointmentStore.createAppointmentCalendarAsync("TEST CALENDAR").done(function (calendar) {
            calendar.saveAppointmentAsync(appointment);
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you're an example to do it using C#

```
        private AppointmentCalendar currentAppCalendar;
    private AsyncLazy<AppointmentStore> lazyAppointmentStore = new AsyncLazy<AppointmentStore>(async () =>
    {
        var appStore = await AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType.AppCalendarsReadWrite);
        return appStore;
    });

    private AppointmentStore AppStore { get { return lazyAppointmentStore.Value.Result; } }

    public AppointmentService()
    {
    }

    public async Task CreateCalendar()
    {
        IReadOnlyList<AppointmentCalendar> appCalendars =
            await AppStore.FindAppointmentCalendarsAsync(FindAppointmentCalendarsOptions.IncludeHidden);

        AppointmentCalendar appCalendar = null;

        // Apps can create multiple calendars. Here app creates only one.
        if (appCalendars.Count == 0)
        {
            appCalendar = await AppStore.CreateAppointmentCalendarAsync(Constants.CalendarName);
        }
        else
        {
            appCalendar = appCalendars[0];
        }

        appCalendar.OtherAppReadAccess = AppointmentCalendarOtherAppReadAccess.Full;
        appCalendar.OtherAppWriteAccess = AppointmentCalendarOtherAppWriteAccess.SystemOnly;

        // This app will show the details for the appointment. Use System to let the system show the details.
        appCalendar.SummaryCardView = AppointmentSummaryCardView.App;

        await appCalendar.SaveAsync();

        currentAppCalendar = appCalendar;
    }

    public async Task<bool> CreateNewAppointment(Data.Schemas.Task task)
    {
        if (null == task)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("task");

        Appointment newAppointment = new Appointment();
        this.SaveAppointmentData(task, newAppointment);

        try
        {
            // Show system calendar to the user to be edited
            string appointmentId = await AppointmentManager.ShowAddAppointmentAsync(newAppointment, Windows.Foundation.Rect.Empty);                
            return ! string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appointmentId);

            // Just save the appointment
            // await currentAppCalendar.SaveAppointmentAsync(newAppointment);                  
            // return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Check [my post](http://geeks.ms/blogs/jlguerrero/archive/2015/06/07/mejorando-la-responsividad-asyc-y-await-asynclazy-lt-t-gt-y-mvvm-as-237-ncrono-notifytaskcompletion-lt-t-gt.aspx), to know more about AsyncLazy.

I hope this help you.
Regards.
Juanlu

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking everywhere for the calendar functionality for windows. To clarify, does a new calendar have to be created everytime you'd like to set a new appointment?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, by using the WinRT appointments API.
A user interaction is always required. It was a design decision by MS that some actions require user interaction and this is one of it.

As stated by @Ken Tucker, you can use the windows live api to create appointments but this requires the user of your app to sing in to windows live and grat it the required permissions.